# Spyder doesn't show image with OpenCV

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, spyder

I am just trying to perform the easiest task in opencv library which is opening and showing an image. I was doing it before on windows computer and it was working perfectly, however when I try to perform the same task on my MacBook it doesn't work. The code is simple:

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('/Users/michalsniady/Desktop/IFE/4th semester/Image Processing And Computer Graphics/nature.jpg', 1)

cv2.imshow('window', img)
cv2.waitKey(10000)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

When I was downloading opencv I used simply pip install opencv-python if I recall correctly. Maybe the version is wrong? I'm using Python 3.7.6

When I run this program it has two outcomes:
- kernel died
- nothing happens
I am using Spyder with Anaconda

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Have you tried doing `cv2.waitKey(0)`?  `waitKey` waits for 10000ms, then closes the window if no key has been pressed.  I realise that it's 10 seconds, but maybe there is something going on in the background that takes a while before the window can show, but it exceeds 10 seconds.  It's a long shot, but try that.  Doing `waitKey(0)` will keep the window up until you push a key.

Comment: Have you tried to run the code from the terminal?

Comment: Try uninstalling opencv-python using `pip uninstall`. Then install opencv using `conda` (command line or anaconda navigator GUI).

Answer (score 0):

I faced somewhat similar issues.
I reinstalled my open CV and then it worked correctly!